# Create an array with all the links of the years' archive (of a custom post type)

Tags: arrays, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I have a custom post type called "papers" and I need to create an array with all the archive links per year that exists. Something like:

```
array (
[0]=> 'http://www.example.com/2021/?post_type=papers'
[1]=> 'http://www.example.com/2019/?post_type=papers'// cause there's no post in 2020
[2]=> 'http://www.example.com/2017/?post_type=papers'
)
```

I've been told to use `get_archives()` but that just gives me a formated list, not an array I can use to feed another function. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $links = wp_get_archives(array('echo'=>'0','format'=>'<link>'));
  $regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
  preg_match_all($regex, $links, $matches);
  $array_links = $matches[0];
  print_r($array_links);
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. This is givining me the arrays but of the main blog, no my custom post types. Is there a way to tweak to make it do that? I don't find a part where that's defined.

Comment: My bad! I just added the  `'post_type' => 'myCPT'` in the `wp_get_archives()` array and it worked. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Can I ask what `/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i'` means?

Comment: This is regex can extract all links from any string

Answer (score -1):

Please try this -

```
function get_archive_post_ids(){
    if( is_archive() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, 'ID' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_archive_post_ids' );
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.  I see you created a function, but when I called it, it doesn't work... or there's a step I'm missing?